# Why is my Angular application not finding the embedded component?

Tags: angular

This is the embedded component, HomeTabComponent.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-tab',
  templateUrl: './home-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-tab.component.scss']
})
export class HomeTabComponent implements OnInit {}
```

The embedded component, HomeTabComponent, is declared in home.module.ts:

```
import { HomeTabComponent } from "./home-tab/home-tab.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, HomeTabComponent],
  exports: [HomeTabComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, HomeRoutingModule],
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

It is then embedded in home.component.html:

```
<section id="product-carousel">
    <app-home-tab></app-home-tab>
</section>
```

But I get the following error:

```
compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-home-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-home-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-home-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' 
of this component to suppress this message. ("
</section>
    <section id="product-carousel">
        [ERROR ->]<app-home-tab></app-home-tab>
        <!-- <div class="row">
```

HomeRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: can you post your HomeRoutingModule definition ?

Comment: Posted HomeRoutingModule

Comment: have you imported HomeTabComponent multiple times in multiple modules ?

Comment: did you find a solution for your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have done it, but you should add your HomeModule inside the imports of your parent NgModule, for example, if you are using it on the app module then:

```
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HomeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Example url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-76w6xq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html